# SVN to HG: Now output SVN revision number from HG changeset

Tags: svn, mercurial

I converted a Subversion repository to Mercurial, using the Convert extension. When I look at the new repository with Tortoise HG, I see in each changeset the corresponding source path and revision (see image). [image: Tortoise HG Screenshot with HG Changeset and SVN source path/revision]

Is there a way to write those two out to the console? Ideally I'd like an output like this:

```
hg:1147 svn:trunk@7201
hg:1146 svn:trunk@7200
...
```

I know that I can use `hg log` with the template option to customize the output, but don't know how to get the Subversion source path/revision.

**EDIT:**
It looks like the way I wanted to go is not possible. The svn source path/revision is in a field called `extras` within the changeset (thanks @Ry4en) and neither `hg log` nor `hg export` output this value. What I will try now is to use the file `.hg/shamap` in combination with

```
hg log --template 'hg:{rev} nodeid:{node}'
```

To map the Mercurial revision to the SVN source path/revision.

**EDIT2:**
My Mercurial version is 1.4.3.
With Mercurial 1.7.1 it's possible to use this command (thanks @ Wim Coenen): `hg log --template {node}\n{extras}\n\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tucked away in a field named `extras` on the changeset, and I don't believe there is a log template entry for it.  It might show up in a `hg export` from which you could grep it, and it's certainly available programmatically, but I don't think there's a `--template` way to get it.

Comment: It looks like you can print `extras`, try `hg log --template {node}\n{extras}\n\n` for example.

Comment: @Wim: When I enter the command like you wrote it (plus single quotes for the template string), I get the message "No keyword 'extra'" (note the missing s). When I just use 'extra' instead of 'extras' I get the log output, but only the node id and no value for the extra field.

Comment: @Ry4en: It seems you're right: There is no way to get the data with `hg log`. Unfortunately I don't see the extras in the `hg export` output either. But I think I can correlate the log output with the entries in .hg/shamap to get the combination I need.

Comment: @Matthias: My example as shown works for me on mercurial 1.7.1. Perhaps you are using an old version?

Comment: @Wim: Yes, I'm using 1.4.3 and there's no word on when I'll get the newer version (at work). I'll keep your suggestion in mind though, thanks :).

Answer (score 9):

New versions of hgsubversion adds a `{svnrev}` template keyword. This is described in `hg help subversion`:

> [...]
>
> **Finding and displaying Subversion revisions**
>
> For revealing the relationship between Mercurial changesets and Subversion
>      revisions, hgsubversion provides three template keywords:
>
> ```
>  svnrev   Expanded to the original Subversion revision number.
>  svnpath  The path within the repository that the changeset represents.
>  svnuuid  The Universally Unique Identifier of the Subversion repository.
> ```
>
> An example:
>
> ```
>  $ hg log --template='{rev}:{node|short} {author|user}\nsvn: {svnrev}\n'
> ```
>
> The template keywords are available when using Mercurial 1.5 or later.
>
> For finding changesets from Subversion, hgsubversion extends revsets to
>      provide two new selectors:
>
> ```
>  fromsvn  Select changesets that originate from Subversion. Takes no
>           arguments.
>  svnrev   Select changesets that originate in a specific Subversion
>           revision. Takes a revision argument.
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  $ hg log -r 'fromsvn()'
>  $ hg log -r 'svnrev(500)'
> ```
>
> Revsets are available when using Mercurial 1.6 or later and are accepted
>      by several Mercurial commands for specifying revisions. See "hg help
>      revsets" for details.

Comment: Does this also work when I did a complete conversion of the SVN repository with the `convert` extension or do I have to use hgsubversion from the beginning?

Comment: He's not using hgsubversion, he's converted the repository.

Comment: @Chris: oh, sorry, I guess I assumed everybody used hgsubversion these days :-)

Comment: @Matthias: I'm afraid you cannot mix a `hg convert` conversion with a hgsubversion conversion.